# Prevent python return type unpacking dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a function written like below.

Basically I would like to use the output from each function as input to the next(subsequent) functions. Not sure why the last function throws error. Can help me on how can I fix this error?

```
def fun_1():
    print("Reading files")
    test_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    test_df = test_df.replace('-',np.nan,regex=True)
    test_map = pd.read_excel('test_map.xlsx')
    test_map = test_map.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())
    return test_df,test_map 

def fun_2(test_df,test_map):
    print("formatting data types and structure")
    test_df['test_datetime'] = test_df['DATE'] +" " + test_df['TIME']
    test_df= test_df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())
    test_df['test_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['test_datetime'])
    return test_df, test_map 

def fun_3(test_df,test_map):
    print("applying data transformation")
    test_df['person_id'] = test_df['subject_id'].map(test_map)
    return test_clean_df

def fun_4(test_clean_df):
    test_clean_df.to_csv('test_clean_df.csv',index=False)
    print("file written")
    return test_clean_df

funcs = [fun_1,fun_2,fun_3,fun_4]

output = []
for func in funcs:
    print(output)
    output = func(*output)
```

I get the below error

> TypeError: fun_4() takes 1 positional argument but 7 were given

Comment: This is because fun_4 takes an argument namely test_clean_df. You can change this line
funcs = [fun_1,fun_2,fun_3,fun_4]  
to
funcs = [fun_1,fun_2,fun_3,fun_4(test_clean_df)]
and you will be good to go

Comment: @AniketRele - I updated the code now. Can help me now please?

Comment: I have arguments for all functions

Comment: To use the return objects from each function to subsequent functions, don't I have to configure them as arguments in the subsequent function like shown in my code?

Comment: What does the final `print(output)` show before the error?

Comment: print(output) shows the final dataframe with 7 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the final `output = func(*output)`, when `func` is `fun_4` you are unpacking the `pandas.DataFrame` object. This passes the columns as positional arguments:

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
In [3]: def f(*args):
   ...:     print(args)
In [4]: f(*df)
('col1', 'col2')
In [5]: f(*(df, df))
(   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4,
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4)
```

If you change your `fun_3` to return a tuple (notice the extra `,` in the `return` on `a()`), that can be unpacked into just the dataframe.

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: def a():
   ...:     return (pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}),)
In [3]: def b(df):
   ...:     print(df)
In [4]: fs = [a, b]
In [5]: out = []
In [6]: for f in fs:
   ...:     out = f(*out)
#    col1  col2
# 0     1     3
# 1     2     4
```

Comment: Okay, so it is like if we return just `one dataframe`, it unpacks them into idvidual columns in dataframe, but if return more than 1 items (multiple items), it treats them as is (due to tuple type)? Am I right to understand this? If it's going to be only one item, then we make sure it's of tuple type by appending `,` to it. Right?

Comment: Yep! That's exactly it. Another way you could resolve this is by checking if the returned value is a tuple with something like `isinstance(output, tuple)` and if it's not, make it one

Comment: @TheGreat, I've added an extra example in the first snippet to show the difference between passing one dataframe and two

Answer (score 0):

Change below part adn you are good to go. The fun_4 takes one argument namely test_clean_df which you are not passing.
test_clean_df will be undefined so get it from fun_3 first.

```
test_clean_df = fun_3()
```

Then run this line

```
**funcs = [fun_1,fun_2,fun_3,fun_4(test_clean_df)]**
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted. can help me based on the updated code?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: isn't this `test_clean_df = fun_3()` done by the chaining operation through `**funcs`? why do we have to assign seperately

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Where is `test_clean_df` coming from? It would be undefined at this point.